How to read portion of a String in Python and store into List
I have a string variable in python and I need to extract all portions that begins and ends with specific strings.
The beginning string is "proc sql" and ending string is "quit;" all lines in between should be extracted to a list;
row ='''proc sql;
        create table answer_1_stg1 as 
        select  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc
                ,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice
                ,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice
                ,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice
                ,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice
        from promo as a
        left join invoice as b
        on 
        a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and
        a.basecode=b.basecode and
        a.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and
        a.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD
        and b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt
        where year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017
        group by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc;
        quit;
        
%sort(answer_1_stg1,descending sum_invoice);

proc sql;
create table answer_1_stg2 as
select distinct promo_mechanic_desc
        ,sum(sum_invoice) as total
from answer_1_stg1;
quit;'''

I need to extract the portions only between two strings, "proc sql" and "quit". The final list should be like this:
lt = ['''proc sql;
        create table answer_1_stg1 as 
        select  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc
                ,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice
                ,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice
                ,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice
                ,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice
        from promo as a
        left join invoice as b
        on 
        a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and
        a.basecode=b.basecode and
        a.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and
        a.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD
        and b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt
        where year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017
        group by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc;
        quit;''','''proc sql;
create table answer_1_stg2 as
select distinct promo_mechanic_desc
        ,sum(sum_invoice) as total
from answer_1_stg1;
quit;''']

I've tried to run the following code, however it only prints the first each line to the list:
fm = []

for i in row.split('\n'):
    if "proc sql" in i:
        print()
        fm.append(i.strip())


however it only prints the first each line to the list Of course, because you're only calling .append() for lines that contain "proc sql".

You'll need to try a little harder - how does your code append lines "between two strings, "proc sql" and "quit""? There are many ways to do this, regular expressions would be an option as well as simply parsing the text for these markers like you are trying to do. Please share a solution you expected to work and explain what problems you're having with it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you should use varaible to control it. Before loop set found = False. In loop when you find line with "proc sql" then set found = True and when you find quit then found = False. And you need also if found: fm.append(i.strip())

You need extra variable to control if you between proc sql and quit
Before loop set i.e found = False.
In loop:

when you find proc sql then set found = True (and set empty fm)
next use if found: fm.append(i)
when you find quit then set found = False (and convert fm to string, and add to lt)

It is important to do it in this order.

Other method is to use regex for this - but I will skip it :)

Minimal working code:
row ='''proc sql;
        create table answer_1_stg1 as 
        select  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc
                ,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice
                ,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice
                ,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice
                ,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice
        from promo as a
        left join invoice as b
        on 
        a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and
        a.basecode=b.basecode and
        a.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and
        a.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD
        and b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt
        where year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017
        group by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc;
        quit;
        
%sort(answer_1_stg1,descending sum_invoice);

proc sql;
create table answer_1_stg2 as
select distinct promo_mechanic_desc
        ,sum(sum_invoice) as total
from answer_1_stg1;
quit;'''

found = False

lt = []
fm = []

for line in row.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if "proc sql" in line:
        found = True
        fm = []
    if found:
        fm.append(line)
    if "quit" in line:
        found = False
        lt.append( "\n".join(fm) )
      
for item in lt:
    print(item)
    print('----')      


Regex is handy for this.
import re

row ='''proc sql;
        create table answer_1_stg1 as 
        select  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc
                ,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice
                ,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice
                ,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice
                ,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice
        from promo as a
        left join invoice as b
        on 
        a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and
        a.basecode=b.basecode and
        a.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and
        a.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD
        and b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt
        where year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017
        group by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD
                ,b.brand_cd
                ,b.category_cd
                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm
                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc;
        quit;
        
%sort(answer_1_stg1,descending sum_invoice);

proc sql;
create table answer_1_stg2 as
select distinct promo_mechanic_desc
        ,sum(sum_invoice) as total
from answer_1_stg1;
quit;'''

regex = r"(proc sql.*?quit)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, row, re.DOTALL)

m = [match.groups()[0] for match in matches]

print(m)

Here is the output. Note that you necessarily lose the formatting of the string so it really can't look exactly like the triple quote string you posted in the question.
['proc sql;\n        create table answer_1_stg1 as \n        select  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD\n                ,b.brand_cd\n                ,b.category_cd\n                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm\n                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc\n                ,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice\n                ,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice\n                ,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice\n                ,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice\n        from promo as a\n        left join invoice as b\n        on \n        a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and\n        a.basecode=b.basecode and\n        a.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and\n        a.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD\n        and b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt\n        where year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017\n        group by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD\n                ,b.brand_cd\n                ,b.category_cd\n                ,a.promo_mechanic_nm\n                ,a.promo_mechanic_desc;\n        quit', 'proc sql;\ncreate table answer_1_stg2 as\nselect distinct promo_mechanic_desc\n        ,sum(sum_invoice) as total\nfrom answer_1_stg1;\nquit']

If you want to clean up the strings more you can iterate though the list and handle \n and white space.
for example
m = ['\n'.join([o.strip() for o in n.split('\n')]) for n in m]

gives the strings with excessive whitespace removed but retains newline markers.
['proc sql;\ncreate table answer_1_stg1 as\nselect  distinct a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD\n,b.brand_cd\n,b.category_cd\n,a.promo_mechanic_nm\n,a.promo_mechanic_desc\n,sum(b.invoice_qty) as sum_invoice\n,avg(b.invoice_qty) as avg_invoice\n,max(b.invoice_qty) as max_invoice\n,min(b.invoice_qty) as min_invoice\nfrom promo as a\nleft join invoice as b\non\na.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD=b.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD and\na.basecode=b.basecode and\na.SALESORG_CD=b.SALESORG_CD and\na.LOCATION_CD=b.LOCATION_CD\nand b.INVOICE_DT between a.event_start_dt and a.event_end_dt\nwhere year(a.event_start_dt) = 2017 and year(b.INVOICE_DT) = 2017\ngroup by a.CUSTOMER_HIERARCHY_LVL2_CD\n,b.brand_cd\n,b.category_cd\n,a.promo_mechanic_nm\n,a.promo_mechanic_desc;\nquit', 'proc sql;\ncreate table answer_1_stg2 as\nselect distinct promo_mechanic_desc\n,sum(sum_invoice) as total\nfrom answer_1_stg1;\nquit']

